# Java - Spring boot - could not autowire - no beans found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Data Loader Class which is suppose to load data once the app starts. 
My Error -

**Could not autowire. No beans of 'OwnerService' Found.**

However, my ownerService class is annotated as I have shown below -

This is the class whose supposed to do that -

**DataLoader**

```
    import model.Owner;
import model.Vet;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import services.OwnerService;
import services.VetService;
import services.map.OwnerServiceMap;
import services.map.VetServiceMap;

@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final OwnerService ownerService;
    private final VetService vetService;



    public DataLoader(OwnerService ownerService, VetService vetService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
        this.vetService = vetService;
    }
```

**OwnerServiceMap**

```
    package services.map;


import model.Owner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import services.OwnerService;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class OwnerServiceMap extends AbstractMapService<Owner,Long> implements OwnerService 

{//some code here}
```

The vetService is the same as ownerService.

**My applcation class -**

```
package petclinic;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PetclinicApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PetclinicApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Maybe I have hierarchy problems, as the application class doesn't search for beans in enough places in the project?

[image: project]

Thank you!

Comment: You have not set the component-scan for the packages

Comment: Can you help with doing that?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-spring-boot-and-component-scan

Comment: @Jens thank you. I have implemented that. Indeed the project compiles, but the error doesn't vanish and the resulted print does not exists. I have implemented @ComponentScan("model") in the project.